# Sendign a file over TCP connection

Tags: python, tcpclient

Im trying to send a file over TCP connection and im spected to receive an accio command but, im having trobule doing that, im getting this error:PS C:\Users\mpgm1\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1> py client.py 131.94.128.43 54634 file.txt
4 131.94.128.43 54634 file.txt
confirm-accio

confirm-accio-again

Sending...
Done Sending
b'ERROR: No data expected until the accio command is issued!'

Here is the code:

```
import selectors
from socket import *
import sock

import sys



print(len(sys.argv), sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], sys.argv[3])

host = sys.argv[1]
port = int(sys.argv[2])
file = sys.argv[3]

# Instaniating socket object
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
# Getting ip_address through host name
host_address = gethostbyname(host)
# Connecting through host's ip address and port number using socket object
s.connect((host_address, port))
print("confirm-accio\r\n")
print("confirm-accio-again\r\n")
fileToSend = open("file.txt", "rb")

print("Sending...")


while True:

    data = fileToSend.read()

    if not data:
        break

    s.send(data)

fileToSend.close()
s.send(b"Done")
print("Done Sending")
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close()
```

Comment: Were the "confirm-accio" strings something you were supposed to send over the network connection?  Printing them to your local terminal seems pointless.  (We can't really tell what your code should be doing, because you're only showing us one end of the connection.)

Comment: How to i send the "confrim accio over the network conenction?